# Are there any cases in which click fraud is legal?

Tags: fraud, cryptocurrency

I recently had an idea for a small cryptocurrency in which instead of paying with real money, you pay with clicks on pay-per-click ads and a portion of the revenue that the website makes off of that single click goes back to the user who clicked it. Apart from that the cryptocurrency works just like every other one so any user could essentially convert those "ClickCoins" back to a real currency (USD) and essentially make money by clicking. Upon researching this idea I stumbled across a term called click fraud ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_fraud)) and was wondering whether that applies to this and if not, is there a way to do this in a legal manner?

Comment: You understand it wrong. Click fraud is not what *you* are doing. Your cryptocurrency idea is click fraud. Click fraud is when one of the *websites* writes a script that clicks on ads on their websites over and over, so your system thinks lots of people are clicking ads on that website, so it pays the website lots of money.  Your cryptocurrency idea is probably *vulnerable* to click fraud.

Comment: I wouldn't be using my ads obviously, I would be using 3rd party ads provided by an external service like Google AdMob.

Comment: Well I don't particularly care whether it's your ads or someone else's ads, either way click fraud is something a website does, not something the ad system does. Also Google won't like you taking away their business. They probably won't let you build a cryptocurrency system based on AdMob